# Content Provider - Updating All Rows and Columns

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have an array of ContentValues[] called cv, which go into my SQLite database. To keep it really simple, my database has these 3 columns (An AutoIncremented ID for each row, the day, and humidity.) The Database has 3 rows. Here is an example of data added to a single row.

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(WeatherContract.WeatherData.COLUMN_DAY_OF_WEEK, day);
        cv.put(WeatherContract.WeatherData.COLUMN_HUMIDITY, humidity);
```

This loops 3 times and each ContentValue is put into my ContentValue array before a bulk insert is made into my database.

I have a Job that grabs new data from a server every five minutes. So I need this new data to replace the old and am having trouble with the Syntax. I get right up to the point where I have ContentValues[] jsonResults with new data and then am a bit confused. How can I update ALL of the rows in my table? Do I need to loop through the contentResolvers update method:

```
for (int i =0; i<jsonResults.length;i++){
            context.getContentResolver().update(weatherQueryUri,jsonResults[i],null,null);
        }
```

If so, what am I placing in my where and selectionArgs clauses instead of null? Or do I keep it null?

After going through the ContentProvider, here is my database method for the actual insertion:

```
  public void updateRow(ContentValues weatherValue,String where, String selection){
        mDb.update(WeatherContract.WeatherData.TABLE_NAME,weatherValue,null,null);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not so sure if my solution works well but you can give it a try.
In order to replace the old data with the new ones, I'd first perform delete() then bulkInsert() on your ContentResolver object. This way you dont have to loop thru the jsonResults.

```
  if (jsonResults != null && jsonResults.length != 0) {
                /* Get a ContentResolver object to help delete and insert data */
                ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

                /* Delete old data */
                contentResolver.delete(weatherQueryUri,null,null);

                /* Insert our new data into contentResolver */
                contentResolver.bulkInsert(weatherQueryUri, jsonResults);
            }
```

Comment: I thought about doing this but the bulkInsert results in the ID changing and I need them to stay the same.